# scikit learn: Problems creating customized CountVectorizer and ChiSquare

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikits, scikit-learn

I have the following code (based on the samples [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html)), but it is not working:

```
[...]
def my_analyzer(s):
    return s.split()
my_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=my_analyzer)
X_train = my_vectorizer.fit_transform(traindata)

ch2 = SelectKBest(chi2,k=1)
X_train = ch2.fit_transform(X_train,Y_train)
[...]
```

The following error is given when calling `fit_transform`:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'analyze'
```

According to the documentation, CountVectorizer should be created like this: `vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=my_tokenizer)`. However, if I do that, I get the following error: `"got an unexpected keyword argument 'tokenizer'"`.

My actual scikit-learn version is 0.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the documentation for 0.11 (to be released soon), where the vectorizer has been overhauled. Check the [documentation for 0.10](http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/modules/feature_extraction.html), where there is no `tokenizer` argument and the `analyzer` should be an object implementing an `analyze` method:

```
class MyAnalyzer(object):
    @staticmethod
    def analyze(s):
        return s.split()

v = CountVectorizer(analyzer=MyAnalyzer())
```

http://scikit-learn.org/dev is the documentation for the upcoming release (which may change at any time), while http://scikit-learn/stable has the documentation for the current stable version.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I also should transform the sparse matrix to array, right? Like this: `ch2.fit_transform(X_train.toarray(), Y_train)` Otherwise non-subscriptable error happens

Comment: @DT: that should never be necessary for chi² feature selection, it's designed to handle sparse matrices. What's the next step in your pipeline?

Comment: Hmm...Strange, chi square requires 2 arrays (X and Y) so I thought I had to convert the sparse matrix to an array...My full code (and a new problem with chisquare features) is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378601/scikit-learn-desired-amount-of-best-features-k-not-selected), could you please take a look?

Comment: I meant, if I call ch2.fit_transform with an sparse matrix, I get a "coo-matrix object is unsubscriptable " error, but goes well if I convert that to an array using toarray()

Comment: @DT: looks like a bug, I'll look into it later today. For now, convert your coo-matrix to CSR format with `.tocsr()` instead of `.toarray()`, that will preserve the sparsity.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! By using the CSR format now works, and selects the features I request without problems! Anyway, it's strange, since a numpy array of size [n_samples, n_features] should be ok according to the documentation... If you want to post your last comment in my other post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378601/scikit-learn-desired-amount-of-best-features-k-not-selected), I can give yours as the answer.

Comment: @DT: yes, a Numpy array should be ok, but in practice you don't want to densify a sparse matrix. I've had workstations freeze when attempting that on large sparse matrices. I've just pushed a patch upstream so chi² will work with COO matrices in 0.11.

Comment: Just an update, I have been trying with more instances, and sometimes it seems that chisq does not give me the actual number of fts I request with k...

Comment: @DT: if it returns more than `k` features, then I just fixed that in the dev version. Otherwise, consider [filing a bug report](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/new).